# How do I refresh Github project on Visual Studio

Tags: github, visual-studio-2019

I am working with someone else on Github and he has changed something, but when I open that Github project on Visual Studio I don't have his changes. How should I resolve this?

I have already looked up this but then I get nothing to do with my problem.

I expect that if my buddy has changed something and I look at Visual Studio I will see his change.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Visual Studio integration with GitHub, but I'm almost certain that you must manually pull changes made to the remote repo. If such a process were automatic, it could cause incredible damage if one party is touching code.

Comment: @AndrewFan yes so how do I do that then